# How handle missing .gps_latitude attributes in an exif image object?

Tags: python-3.x, exif

My script to retrieve gps exif data only works when **all files** in the path have gps attributes but my problem is: it turns out that not all files in my directory have gps data so when the script reachs one of those files it raises an error *“AttributeError: image does not have attribute gps_latitude”*, my question is how automatically skip those files or handle that error?

*PD. All files have exif data (image.has_exif==True) but some of them dont have gps data for some reason*

```
files_path=Path.home()/'my path'
file_txt_path=Path.home()/'my coordinates file path'

files=list(files_path.glob("IMG_*.jpg"))

dict_files_data={}

for file in files:
   with open(file,'rb') as src:
      img=Image(src)

      data=img.gps_latitude
      latitude=(data[0]+data[1]/60+data[2]/3600)*(-1)
           
      data1=img.gps_longitude
      longitude=(data1[0]+data1[1]/60+data1[2]/3600)*(-1)
          
      dict_files_data[file.name]=[latitude,longitude,img.datetime]
```

Comment: Please put back your `import` statements so we know what libraries you are using.

Comment: Maybe use a `try/except` around reading them. Sometimes the GPS has not stabilised/fixed a position when you press the shutter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getattr`, providing an default argument in case the attributes are not set:

```
...
for file in files:
   with open(file,'rb') as src:
      img=Image(src)

      data = getattr(img, 'gps_latitude', None)
      data1 = getattr(img, 'gps_longitude', None)

      if not (data and data1):
          continue          

      latitude=(data[0]+data[1]/60+data[2]/3600)*(-1)
           
      data1=img.gps_longitude
      longitude=(data1[0]+data1[1]/60+data1[2]/3600)*(-1)
          
      dict_files_data[file.name]=[latitude,longitude,img.datetime]
```

Did you try other tools ([exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), [exiv2](https://exiv2.org/), ...) to read GPS data, maybe it's just a lack of the module you are using ?